# JupyterLab notebook on Google AI Platform superslow when making predictions

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have uploaded a trained tensorflow v2 model onto the Google AI Platform to make predictions on unseen data.
This data is stored in Google Cloud Storage in shards, each c 300 MB large.

I am using a notebook to preprocess the data, which works fine.
When making predictions on the preprocessed data, it works but it is superslow, around 90 minutes for just a file of 300 MB. I got quite a few of these shards so I have to find a way to speed things up.

I have tried different notebook configurations in terms of cpu, RAM and even gpu but it does not make a difference on the prediction runtime.

Am I missing something? Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: you data is persistent in Google Cloud Storage? does the uploading speed fast? And how to access that in jupyterlab? I upload data directly to jupyterlab. The uploading speed is superslow.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to optimize the a model for serving the most impotant considerations are

1: Model size

2: Prediction speed

3: Prediction throughput

Several techniques exist in TensorFlow that will allow you to shrink the size of a model and improve prediction latency.As per offical documentation

"Freezing: 
    Convert the variables stored in a checkpoint file of the SavedModel into
    constants stored directly in the model graph. This reduces the overall size of       the model.

Pruning: 
    Strip unused nodes in the prediction path and the outputs of the graph, merging       duplicate nodes, as well as cleaning other node ops like summary, identity, etc.

Constant folding: 
    Look for any sub-graphs within the model that always evaluate to constant             expressions, and replace them with those constants.

Folding batch norms: 
    Fold the multiplications introduced in batch normalization into the weight           multiplications of the previous layer.

Quantization: 
    Convert weights from floating point to lower precision, such as 16 or 8 bits.

The actual process would be something like this

1. Freeze the SavedModel:
       SavedModel ⇒ GraphDef
2. Optimize the frozen model:
       GraphDef ⇒ GraphDef
3. Convert the optimized frozen model back to SavedModel:
       GraphDef ⇒ SavedModel

A very good post detailing the entire optimization for serving can be found here
Optimizing TensorFlow Models for Serving [1](https://medium.com/google-cloud/optimizing-tensorflow-models-for-serving-959080e9ddbf)